# i tried to implement AsyncTask in my weather application.It shows following error String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();

Tags: android

i get the error in the following line 
String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
it shows "The method QueryYahooWeather() is undefined for the type AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity"

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity extends Activity {

TextView weather;
TextView txtcity;
TextView txtregion;
TextView txtcountry;
TextView txttemp;
TextView txtpressure;
TextView txthumidity;
TextView txtspeed;
TextView txtsunrise;
TextView txtsunset;
TextView txtcondition;

TextView day1;
TextView date1;
TextView low1;
TextView high1;
TextView text1;
TextView day2;
TextView date2;
TextView low2;
TextView high2;
TextView text2;

ImageView img;
ImageView nxtday1;
ImageView nxtday2;


class MyWeather {
    WeatherImageHandler im = new WeatherImageHandler(getApplicationContext());
    WeatherImageHandler im1 = new WeatherImageHandler(getApplicationContext());
    WeatherImageHandler im2 = new WeatherImageHandler(getApplicationContext());
    String description;
    String city;
    String region;
    String country;

    String windChill;
    String windDirection;
    String windSpeed;

    String sunrise;
    String sunset;

    String conditiontext;
    String conditiondate;

    String temp;
    String pressure;
    String humidity;
    String visibility;
    String code;

    String rising;

    // //<yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="28 Nov 2012" low="65" high="87"
    // text="Partly Cloudy" code="29" />
    String day;
    String date;
    String low;
    String high;
    String text;
    String code0;

    String day1;
    String date1;
    String low1;
    String high1;
    String text1;
    String code1;

    String day2;
    String date2;
    String low2;
    String high2;
    String text2;
    String code2;
    //String[] arrDay = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };

    public String toString() {

        return "\n- " + description + " -\n\n" + "city: " + city + "\n"
                + "region: " + region + "\n" + "country: " + country
                + "\n\n"

                + "Wind\n" + "chill: " + windChill + "\n" + "direction: "
                + windDirection + "\n" + "speed: " + windSpeed + "\n\n"

                + "Sunrise: " + sunrise + "\n" + "Sunset: " + sunset
                + "\n\n"

                + "Condition: " + conditiontext + "\n" + conditiondate
                + "\n\n" + "temp:" + temp + "\n" + "pressure:" + pressure
                + "\n" + "humidity" + humidity + "\n" + "rising" + rising
                + "\n" + "visibility" + visibility + "\n"+"code  :" +code+"\n\n"

                + "day  :" + day
                + "\n" + "date  :" + date + "\n" + "low  :" + low + "\n" + "high  :"
                + high+ "\n" + "text  :" + text+"\n"+"code"+code0+"\n\n"

                + "day  :" + day1
                + "\n" + "date  :" + date1 + "\n" + "low  :" + low1 + "\n" + "high  :"
                + high1+ "\n" + "text  :" + text1+"code"+code1+"\n\n"

                + "day  :" + day2
                + "\n" + "date  :" + date2 + "\n" + "low  :" + low2 + "\n" + "high  :"
                + high2+ "\n" + "text  :" + text2+"code"+code2;


    }
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //weather = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
    txtcity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
    txtregion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.region);
    txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
    txttemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
    txtpressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressure);
    txthumidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidity);
    txtspeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
    txtsunrise = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sunrise);
    txtsunset = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sunset);
    txtcondition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.condition);

    day1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day1);
    date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date1);
    low1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.low1);
    high1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.high1);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    day2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day2);
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    low2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.low2);
    high2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.high2);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);


    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    nxtday1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextday1);
    nxtday2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextday2);

    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
    Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

    MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
    txtcity.setText(weatherResult.city);
    txtregion.setText(weatherResult.region);
    txtcountry.setText(weatherResult.country);
    txttemp.setText(weatherResult.temp);
    txtpressure.setText(weatherResult.pressure);
    txthumidity.setText(weatherResult.humidity);
    txtspeed.setText(weatherResult.windSpeed);
    txtsunrise.setText(weatherResult.sunrise);
    txtsunset.setText(weatherResult.sunset);
    txtcondition.setText(weatherResult.date);

    day1.setText(weatherResult.day);
    date1.setText(weatherResult.date);
    low1.setText(weatherResult.low);
    high1.setText(weatherResult.high);
    text1.setText(weatherResult.text);

    day2.setText(weatherResult.day1);
    date2.setText(weatherResult.date1);
    low2.setText(weatherResult.low1);
    high2.setText(weatherResult.high1);
    text2.setText(weatherResult.text1);

    img.setImageDrawable(weatherResult.im.getWeatherImage());
    nxtday1.setImageDrawable(weatherResult.im1.getWeatherImage());
    nxtday2.setImageDrawable(weatherResult.im2.getWeatherImage());
}

    private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc) {

    MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();


    myWeather.description = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")
            .item(0).getTextContent();


    Node locationNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:location")
            .item(0);
    myWeather.city = locationNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("city")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.region = locationNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("region")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.country = locationNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("country").getNodeValue().toString();


    Node windNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:wind").item(0);
    myWeather.windChill = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("chill")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.windDirection = windNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("direction").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.windSpeed = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed")
            .getNodeValue().toString();


    Node atmosphereNode = srcDoc
            .getElementsByTagName("yweather:atmosphere").item(0);
    myWeather.humidity = atmosphereNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("humidity").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.visibility = atmosphereNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("visibility").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.pressure = atmosphereNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("pressure").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.rising = atmosphereNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("rising").getNodeValue().toString();


    Node astronomyNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:astronomy")
            .item(0);
    myWeather.sunrise = astronomyNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("sunrise").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.sunset = astronomyNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("sunset")
            .getNodeValue().toString();


    Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition")
            .item(0);
    myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.conditiondate = conditionNode.getAttributes()
            .getNamedItem("date").getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.temp = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("temp")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.code = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("code")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.im.setWeatherImage(myWeather.code);


    Node forecastNode1 = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast")
            .item(0);
    myWeather.day = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("day")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.date = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.low = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("low")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.high = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("high")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.text = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.code0 = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("code")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.im1.setWeatherImage(myWeather.code0);


    Node forecastNode2 = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast")
            .item(1);
    myWeather.day1 = forecastNode2.getAttributes().getNamedItem("day")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.date1 = forecastNode2.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.low1 = forecastNode2.getAttributes().getNamedItem("low")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.high1 = forecastNode2.getAttributes().getNamedItem("high")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.text1 = forecastNode2.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.code1 = forecastNode1.getAttributes().getNamedItem("code")
            .getNodeValue().toString();
    myWeather.im2.setWeatherImage(myWeather.code1);



    return myWeather;
}

private Document convertStringToDocument(String src) {
    Document dest = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser;

    try {
        parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes()));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, e1.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return dest;
}
public class weather extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    private String QueryYahooWeather () 
    {


    String qResult = "";
    String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295422";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

    try {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

        if (httpEntity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String stringReadLine = null;

            while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
            }

            qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity.this, e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return qResult;
}
```

}}

it also shows "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody" but every braces are completely closed.

Comment: For future reference, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - you've posted nearly 400 lines of badly-formatted code, which has made it harder to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    private String QueryYahooWeather () 
    {
```

You've tried to declare one method within another. You can't do that.

That's the main source of both your problems. (The braces are incorrect because you need to close `doInBackground` before starting the `QueryYahooWeather` method, and the `QueryYahooWeather` can't be found because you haven't declared it properly.)

Next up, you've actually posted the source for two different classes (it wasn't obvious because you haven't indented the code appropriately, and there's rather a lot of it). The call to `QueryYahooWeather` is within `AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity`, but the method itself is declared within the `weather` class.

You should *either* move the method *or* use an instance of `weather` to call it. It's not clear to me exactly how you should redesign this code, although I suspect you'll have to do so significantly. Aside from anything else, you shouldn't be making any network calls synchronously in the UI thread. You should probably make your asynchronous task call back to populate your UI when it completes, rather than trying to just fetch the result synchronously.

Given this design issue, I would *strongly* recommend starting a second project *just* to get that bit right. You've got an awful lot of code at the moment, and most of it isn't needed to get the right design solution for the problem of "how do I query Yahoo Weather and show the results in a UI". Once you've worked out the right design in a simpler project, you can apply it to your more complicated one.

Additionally, I'd recommend renaming the method to `queryYahooWeather` to comply with Java naming conventions. Likewise the `weather` class should be *at least* `Weather`, but preferrably something more descriptive. Finally, I'd suggest putting each class in its own source file, to make your project easier to navigate.

Comment: but i still get an error in the same line 
String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();"The method QueryYahooWeather() is undefined for the type AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity"

Comment: @Ragavi: I've just noticed that in the huge wall of code of your question there were actually two classes. It looks like you're declaring `QueryYahooWeather` in the `weather` class, but you're trying to call it from `AndroidYahooWeatherDOMActivity`. To do that, you'll need to have an instance of `weather`. Your design isn't clear enough to me to say whether the method is in the right place and you need an instance of `weather`, or whether you should move the method. (I'll edit the answer.)

Comment: @Ragavi: I've edited my answer with a few pointers. Please read the updated version carefully.